# Rails2 - ActiveRecord query to find records based on the condition of associated records

Tags: mysql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

*How to find all posts in which a particular user(with user_id) not commented?*

Data model is as follows,

```
User
----
(no direct association to Post and Comment)

Post
----
belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
has_many :comments


Comment
-------
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :commentor, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
```

I have tried as follows but it still gives posts that are commented by user already,

```
Post.find(:all, :include => [:comments], :conditions => ["posts.user_id != ? AND comments.user_id != ?",  user.id, user.id])
```

And I am able to find all posts that are commented by particular user as follows,

```
Post.find(:all, :include => [:comments], :conditions => ["posts.user_id != ? AND comments.user_id = ?",  user.id, user.id])
```

Please help me out in finding the expected results.

Comment: @venky Can you please try this:

`Post.find(:all, :include => [:comments], :conditions => ["posts.user_id != ? AND comments.user_id <> ?",  user.id, user.id])`

Comment: @SourabhUpadhyay - Tried but I got the same result :(